# How to get errors / debug AMPScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to build a complex email (several dynamic zones, unique content per user using multiple data extensions).

To check AMPScript syntax errors, I use `Validate`, but I didn't find a way to get runtime errors (ie. related to the content of look up rows). I know there's an error since `Send Preview` gives `There was an error building your preview.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFMC Support can give you the details of the exception <strike>, unless you're working with a partner that has access to the server error log in 3Sixty</strike>.

I would start cutting out bits of code and adding them back in one at a time until I find the offending line -- that is unless you'd like to post some redacted code so we can help you.

Since it's a runtime error, I'd suggest looking a the values you're retrieving and the any operations you're performing on them (e.g. retrieving a value that's empty and then doing an `indexOf()` on it).

**Edit:** No Partners have access to the error log anymore :(

Comment: Thanks, that's what I have done : cut my email in small parts and see which one is not working. I found why, using %%= v(@SomeValue) =%% to debug, it's just a bit cumbersome.

Comment: I'm spoiled by having access to the error log, since it makes debugging these types of things a heck of a lot easier.    Same is true for Query Activity debugging.

Comment: This system is truly awful if that is the correct answer.